# Recorrer Array en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, array

Estoy recorriendo el siguiente array:

```
$register = array_values($array);
    foreach($register as $key => $value) {
        $var = explode('"', $value[0]);

        $transfer = new Transfers;
        $transfer->date = Carbon::CreateFromFormat("d/m/Y", $var[1])->format('Y-m-d');
        $transfer->bank_id = 1;
        $transfer->reference = $var[3];
        $transfer->description = $var[5];
        $transfer->amount = $var[7];
        $transfer->status = "Sin validar";
        $transfer->save();            
    }
```

Al momento de hacerle un `dd($var[i])`, imprime sin ningun problema, pero al continuar para registrar, me devuelve lo siguiente: **Undefined offset: 1**

Comment: Puedes añadir un dump de $register? Es que no veo que tiene $value[0], donde haces el explode. En qué parte haces el dd($var[i])  que comentas?

Comment: X2 a lo que dice Jakala. de ser posible, añade también el del `$array` inicial.

Comment: Solucionado. El explode me estaba generando otro array, por eso $var no tenia una valor especifico.

Comment: Estas accediendo a un elemento del arreglo que no existe.

Answer (score 0):

El error lo dice, no existe el índice en el array que se crea de lo que te devuelve `explode`, comprueba que cuando realizas `explode` siempre te devuelva el ó los índices a los que quieres acceder.

Comment: Solucionado. El explode me estaba generando otro array, por eso $var no tenia una valor especifico.